# React Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, reactjs

I've been trying to integrate React into my Rails project, but I keep running into this error:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

I have no idea why this would be coming up, can anyone give me a hand?

app.coffee.erb

```
reactReady = -> 
    officerModals = React.createClass
        render: ->
            React.DOM.div
                className: 'photo'
                React.DOM.h2
                    className: 'officer'

    React.render React.createElement(officerModals, {}), $('#officerPics')

$(document).ready reactReady
$(document).on 'page:load', reactReady
```

HTML:

```
<div id="officersPage" class="row">
     <div id="officerPics"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is because `$('#officerPics')` will not return a DOM element.  It will return a JQuery object.

In order to [get the DOM object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/) you need to pull it out:

```
$('#officerPics').get( 0 );
```